# Create a class with a "ndarray" attribute

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a class that looks like this :

```
class MyStructure:
    def __init__(self, ndarray_type):
        self.data = ndarray_type
```

And I want to pass an object of this class as an argument to other classes. For example :

```
class Edit:
    def __init__(self, structureObject):
        self.data = structureObject

    def Gray(self, image):
        r,g,b = image[:,:,0], image[:,:,1], image[:,:,2]
        gray = 0.2989*r + 0.5870*g + 0.1140*b
        return gray
```

Edit : I get an error when I run this :

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
im = imread('filename.jpg')
temp1 = MyStructure(im)
temp2 = Edit(temp1)
result = temp2.Gray(temp1)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

Line 1 : result = temp2.Gray(temp1)

Line 5, in Gray : r,g,b = image[:,:,0], image[:,:,1], image[:,:,2]

AttributeError: MyStructure instance has no attribute '**getitem**'

Comment: What exactly causes the error? There's no call for MyStructure in your code sample? Also take a look into class inheritance: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance , It's no a solution to your problem, just a different methodology you can use depending on circumstances.

Comment: You missing something.... Like @armatita said. What causes the error? Anyway, add
`def __getitem__(self, index):        
    return self.data[index]`
to `MyStructure`... It might help.

Comment: `image` is an instance of `MyStructure` which does not implement `[..]` access. What is your intention ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get error because you are trying to treat object of class *MyStructure* as object of class *numpy.ndarray* and that's not true. The data which you want to assign to *r, g, b* sits in attribute *data* of object of class *MyStructure*. Attribute *data* is an instance of *numpy.ndarray*.

If it's still not clear, maybe this will help:

```
temp1.__class__  # result: <class '__main__.MyStructure'>
temp1.data.__class__  # result: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

To make it work, you can modify the definition of method *Gray* to:

```
def Gray(self, image):
    r,g,b = image.data[:,:,0], image.data[:,:,1], image.data[:,:,2]
    gray = 0.2989*r + 0.5870*g + 0.1140*b
    return gray
```

Answer (score 0):

`image` is an instance of `MyStructure` which does not implement `[..]` access. You have to implement a `__getitem__` method of `MyStructure` which forwards this access to your `data` attribute to enable this:

```
class MyStructure:
    def __init__(self, ndarray_type):
        self.data = ndarray_type
    def __getitem__(self, *a):
        return self.data.__getitem__(*a)
```

What is your intention ?